# Program exited with code: 5 - Geany with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, exit, geany

my issue: when I compile and build my program in C (using gcc compiler and geany as editor), no problem, fil object and executable are fine. But when I try to execute from Geany or manually from Prompt (as Admin), I get this kind of error. It became to appear after installing Visual Studio, I don't know if it causes some issue like this. Before its installation I had no problem.

I've set all kinds of permission, r/w files and dirs, but everytime I go view Property File of my .exe I find "Read Only" permission. Then, I try to execute, Promt give me exit error code 5 and my .exe file have been deleted automatically.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks all folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit error code 5 means access denied. Together with the executable being deleted automatically, that points to your antivirus being at fault. Replace it with a better one.